# Define variable in a class

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am trying to figure out how to use a variable in a class.

From another question ([Macro for Declaring Variables in Class Files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93908/macro-for-declaring-variables-in-class-files)) I got started. However, I find myself in need of using four lines or rather unclear code. This is what I have:

```
\let\@headertitle\relax
\def\headertitle#1{\def\@headertitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\printheadertitle}{\@headertitle}
\printheadertitle{} % This will print the string in the variable
```

It works, but doesn't look good. I simply want to use `\headertitle{string}` in my document, and be able to somehow call it (e.g. `\headertitle{}` within my class. Can I simplify this?

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47438/5872) should be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first and fourth lines are not doing anything very useful, so you can simplify by removing them, then:

If your class or package code has

```
\def\headertitle#1{\def\@headertitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\printheadertitle}{\@headertitle}
```

then your document can go

```
\headertitle{hello world}
```

and at any point later

```
\printheadertitle
```

will produce `hello world`

This will mean that you get an error if `\printheadertitle` is used without defining a title. If you want a default title to be silently accepted add in your class code

```
\headertitle{}
```

or some default other than empty.