# Calling macro fails with error \inaccessible

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

I am trying to define a macro which I will include in a class definition. For the time being I put the macro definition in the normal document. Compiling the following document fails.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ntcstitle#1{\def{\@ntcstitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\thentcstitle}{\@ntcstitle}
\makeatother

\ntcstitle{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{document}
\thentcstitle\par
\end{document}
```

This example is something I copied from another question here, which seemed to work:

[Define variable in a class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112189/define-variable-in-a-class)

I also tried to move this definition into a class file, omitted the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands. Using the class file was successful, the error message is the same.

This is the error message:

> ```
> ! Missing control sequence inserted.
>  <inserted text> 
>                 \inaccessible 
>  l.10 \ntcstitle{Lorem Ipsum}
> ```

Then I replaced the macro with the LaTeX style definition:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ntcstitle}[1]{\newcommand{\@ntcstitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\thentcstitle}{\@ntcstitle}
\makeatother

\ntcstitle{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{document}
\thentcstitle\par
\end{document}
```

And that works as expected.

I tried to use `\def` instead of `\newcommand` because I assumed `\def` was the correct way to define macros in class files. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `\newcommand` if you can as it is safer. What is the purpose of the command exactly? I'm not sure why you are defining 3 different commands.

Comment: Although I admit to writing it, you might find [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172511/) helpful. `\newcommand` is LaTeX. `\def` is TeX. Only use `\def` when you know why `\newcommand` isn't suitable.

Comment: Your code seems to be equivalent to `\newcommand{\ntcstitle}[1]{\newcommand{\thentcstitle}{#1}}`?

Comment: @cfr: The intention of the command is to define \@ntcstitle. Later I use the macro \thentcstitle to print the variable \@ntcstitle. I define the macro to set \@ntcstitle only once, but two different MWE.

Comment: @cfr: If \newcommand is the preferred way, I'll use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `\def` in latex but if you do the syntax is

```
   \def\@ntcstitle{#1}}
```

not

```
   \def{\@ntcstitle}{#1}}
```

(The `#1` and the trailing `}` of course only valid in the context of your definition of `\ntcstitle`)

Comment: @paul The extra brace was intentional, I'll add a note in the answer

Comment: That is a stupid mistake. I have looked for 2 days at this code and the example and I did not notice the {}. Aaarrggghhhh

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for my miscorrection: I did not read carefully the question...

Comment: @jlinkels: I strongly feel with you! Well, you should admit yourself that the error message was not exactly helpful to find the culprit.